# Building a GUI Form Using Pascal

Tags: user-interface, macos, pascal

I'm emulating a old Macintosh(IIci) and using CodeWarrior 1 Gold 68k, but how I can design a Form on it only by using code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better late than never. You will need the Inside Macintosh manuals, *Macintosh Toolbox Essentials* and possibly *More Macintosh Toolbox*. They were released in digital form; you might find a CD image online. (They predated PDF, though, so you'll need your emulator to read the files.)

Use the Window Manager to open a window, and the Control Manager to populate it with your form and handle interaction.

Of course, you're better off using ResEdit, the granddaddy of all form editors. Click and drag to create a dialog box, and `GetNewDialog` will get you going in no time.

Edit: You might also consider MPW, Apple's command-line toolchain, which might have a steeper curve than CodeWarrior 1 but also was a mature product people actually used ;v) . Still available free 9 years after the last release: http://developer.apple.com/tools/mpw-tools/ .

Answer (score 1):

Ow. That's old. I did the same thing but slightly different tools.

In years of yore, I managed to startup lazarus using FPC 1.0.10 on a IIci with NetBSD installed. FPC 1.0.x supported m68k.

(while thinking about it, to be precise I ported FPC on the IIci with a 68030 50 MHz accelerator + FPU, and started/built lazarus only on a 840AV (68040/40)).